# Can a RESTfull service method send any Object to the client?

Tags: java, rest

I have a restfull service , in that service i should send one inputstream object to the client. So i wrote the following code...in service method..

```
@GET
@Path("/getFile")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public InputStream getFile() throws Exception {
FileInputStream fin = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;
System.out.println("getFile called in server...");
File serverFile = null;
System.out.println("getfile called..");
try {
    serverFile = new File("E:\\Sample2.txt");
    fin = new FileInputStream(serverFile);
    dis = new DataInputStream(fin);
    fin.close();
   // dis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in server appl..***************");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return dis;
}
```

In my client application im calling this service as...

```
 String clientURL = "http://xxxxxxx:xxxx/RestfullApp02/resources/LoadFile";
 Client client = Client.create();
 WebResource webResource = client.resource(clientURL);

 InputStream ob = webResource.path("getFile").get(InputStream.class);
```

But i unable to get the response , it sending 500 error.. like below errror....

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://myIp:myport/RestfullApp02/resources/LoadFile/getFile returned a response status of 500
```

Help Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the below link, I feel you can solve the issue by it.

http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2011/11/returning-binary-file-from-rest-service.html

Comment: when we return the inputstream object .. before returning only it vl close the inputstream.. then when v can read the stream data..       


Could you tell me how client can call this method and get the InputStream object....

Comment: A piece of code from your Question will work for this:    
InputStream ob = webResource.path("getFile").get(InputStream.class);